# Saving files in physical location in all WFEs of the farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssom

I have a farm with 3 servers, 2 WFEs and one out of rotation for crawling. I need to save files in physical location in 2 WFEs through SSOM code. How can i do it?

Thanks 
Diwakar

Comment: Code. It usually works!